# Error while using latest Swagger-ui-react with NX and webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack, swagger-ui, nrwl-nx

I'm getting an error when trying to build simple nx app that uses swagger-ui-react component.

Below is the error

```
ERROR in ../../node_modules/.pnpm/swagger-ui-react@5.11.0_@types+react@18.0.28_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/swagger-ui-react/swagger-ui.css (../../node_modules/.pnpm/swagger-ui-react@5.11.0_@types+react@18.0.28_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/swagger-ui-react/swagger-ui.css.webpack[javascript/auto]!=!../../node_modules/.pnpm/css-loader@6.9.1_webpack@5.89.0/node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[5].oneOf[4].use[1]!../../node_modules/.pnpm/postcss-loader@6.2.1_postcss@8.4.33_webpack@5.89.0/node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[5].oneOf[4].use[2]!../../node_modules/.pnpm/swagger-ui-react@5.11.0_@types+react@18.0.28_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/swagger-ui-react/swagger-ui.css)
Module Error (from ../../node_modules/.pnpm/postcss-loader@6.2.1_postcss@8.4.33_webpack@5.89.0/node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):
<css input>:191:8: Can't resolve '"data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,<svg xmlns=/"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg/" width=/"24/" height=/"24/"><path d=/"M10 6 8.59 7.41 13.17 12l-4.58 4.59L10 18l6-6z/"/></svg>"' in '/Users/ameshram/workspaces/react_workspaces/nx_demo/react-monorepo/node_modules/.pnpm/swagger-ui-react@5.11.0_@types+react@18.0.28_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/swagger-ui-react'
```

App.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import SwaggerUI from 'swagger-ui-react';
import 'swagger-ui-react/swagger-ui.css';

function App() {
  return <SwaggerUI url="https://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json" />;
}

export default App;
```

webpack.config.js

```
const { composePlugins, withNx } = require('@nrwl/webpack');
const { withReact } = require('@nrwl/react');

// Nx plugins for webpack.
module.exports = composePlugins(withNx(), withReact(), (config) => {
  // Update the webpack config as needed here.
  // e.g. `config.plugins.push(new MyPlugin())`

  return config;
});
```

package.json

```
    {
  "name": "react-monorepo",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {},
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "swagger-ui-react": "~5.11.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.14.5",
    "@nrwl/cypress": "15.9.5",
    "@nrwl/eslint-plugin-nx": "15.9.5",
    "@nrwl/jest": "15.9.5",
    "@nrwl/js": "15.9.5",
    "@nrwl/linter": "15.9.5",
    "@nrwl/nx-cloud": "latest",
    "@nrwl/react": "15.9.5",
    "@nrwl/webpack": "15.9.5",
    "@nrwl/workspace": "15.9.5",
    "@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin": "^0.5.7",
    "@svgr/webpack": "^6.1.2",
    "@testing-library/react": "14.0.0",
    "@types/jest": "^29.4.0",
    "@types/node": "18.14.2",
    "@types/react": "18.0.28",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.0.11",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.36.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.36.1",
    "babel-jest": "^29.4.1",
    "cypress": "^12.17.4",
    "eslint": "~8.15.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "8.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-cypress": "^2.10.3",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.27.5",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.7.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.32.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "4.6.0",
    "jest": "^29.4.1",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.4.1",
    "nx": "15.9.5",
    "prettier": "^2.6.2",
    "react-refresh": "^0.10.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
    "ts-jest": "^29.0.5",
    "ts-node": "10.9.1",
    "typescript": "~4.9.5",
    "url-loader": "^4.1.1",
    "@types/swagger-ui-react": "~4.18.3"
  }
}
```

project.json

```
{
  "name": "swagger-ui-demo",
  "$schema": "../../node_modules/nx/schemas/project-schema.json",
  "sourceRoot": "apps/swagger-ui-demo/src",
  "projectType": "application",
  "targets": {
    "build": {
      "executor": "@nrwl/webpack:webpack",
      "outputs": ["{options.outputPath}"],
      "defaultConfiguration": "production",
      "options": {
        "compiler": "babel",
        "outputPath": "dist/apps/swagger-ui-demo",
        "index": "apps/swagger-ui-demo/src/index.html",
        "baseHref": "/",
        "main": "apps/swagger-ui-demo/src/main.tsx",
        "tsConfig": "apps/swagger-ui-demo/tsconfig.app.json",
        "assets": [
          "apps/swagger-ui-demo/src/favicon.ico",
          "apps/swagger-ui-demo/src/assets"
        ],
        "styles": ["apps/swagger-ui-demo/src/styles.css"],
        "scripts": [],
        "isolatedConfig": true,
        "webpackConfig": "apps/swagger-ui-demo/webpack.config.js"
      },
      "configurations": {
        "development": {
          "extractLicenses": false,
          "optimization": false,
          "sourceMap": true,
          "vendorChunk": true
        },
        "production": {
          "fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "apps/swagger-ui-demo/src/environments/environment.ts",
              "with": "apps/swagger-ui-demo/src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
            }
          ],
          "optimization": true,
          "outputHashing": "all",
          "sourceMap": false,
          "namedChunks": false,
          "extractLicenses": true,
          "vendorChunk": false
        }
      }
    },
    "serve": {
      "executor": "@nrwl/webpack:dev-server",
      "defaultConfiguration": "development",
      "options": {
        "buildTarget": "swagger-ui-demo:build",
        "hmr": true
      },
      "configurations": {
        "development": {
          "buildTarget": "swagger-ui-demo:build:development"
        },
        "production": {
          "buildTarget": "swagger-ui-demo:build:production",
          "hmr": false
        }
      }
    },
    "lint": {
      "executor": "@nrwl/linter:eslint",
      "outputs": ["{options.outputFile}"],
      "options": {
        "lintFilePatterns": ["apps/swagger-ui-demo/**/*.{ts,tsx,js,jsx}"]
      }
    },
    "serve-static": {
      "executor": "@nrwl/web:file-server",
      "options": {
        "buildTarget": "swagger-ui-demo:build"
      }
    },
    "test": {
      "executor": "@nrwl/jest:jest",
      "outputs": ["{workspaceRoot}/coverage/{projectRoot}"],
      "options": {
        "jestConfig": "apps/swagger-ui-demo/jest.config.ts",
        "passWithNoTests": true
      },
      "configurations": {
        "ci": {
          "ci": true,
          "codeCoverage": true
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "tags": []
}
```

If I `run` the application using following command, it works and swagger ui is displayed.

```
pnpm nx run swagger-ui-demo:serve
```

If I `build` the application using following command, it gives error.

```
pnpm nx run swagger-ui-demo:build
```

I was not getting this error while using older version of swagger-ui-react i.e. 3.52.5. While upgrading to swagger-ui-react 5.11.0 only I am getting this error.

Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem.  I ended up copying the file in my code in a `swagger-ui.scss` file.

Scss loader doesn't have any problem to load this style.